# Получить процесс загрузки файла

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    function update__account_avatar(original) {

        var $input = $("#update_photo_form__account");
        var fd = new FormData;

        fd.append('photo', $input.prop('files')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/data/users/avatar/upload',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.status == 'error') {
                    var notyf = new Notyf();
                    notyf.alert(data.msg);
                    $("#update_photo_src__account").attr("src", original);
                } else {
                    var notyf = new Notyf();
                    notyf.confirm(data.msg);
                    $("#update_photo_src__account").attr("src", data.src);
                }

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Как отображать в реальном времени сколько данных (в процентах) уже передалось на сервер?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться таким плагином: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function update__account_avatar(original) {

        var $input = $("#update_photo_form__account");
        var fd = new FormData;

        fd.append('photo', $input.prop('files')[0]);

        $.ajax({
             xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                         var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                         percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                         console.log(percentComplete);

                         if (percentComplete === 100) {
                              //
                         }

                    }
                }, false);

                return xhr;
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/data/users/avatar/upload',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.status == 'error') {
                    var notyf = new Notyf();
                    notyf.alert(data.msg);
                    $("#update_photo_src__account").attr("src", original);
                } else {
                    var notyf = new Notyf();
                    notyf.confirm(data.msg);
                    $("#update_photo_src__account").attr("src", data.src);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```